# Date range Filter- SQL -

Tags: mysql, sql, date, google-sheets

I have a table including columns with dates. From this I want to count the number of dates between a date range for each column: `Date new`, `Date HR Screening`, `Date HM Interview`.

Is there a way to count the number of dates for each column using 1 date filter for all the columns? (see example below)

From my understanding, I can only do this with data (`date` in this case) from the table.

**Example - Filter:**

Start date: 2017-01-01

End date: 2017 -01-31

**And the result would be:**

Date new: 150

Date HR Screening: 100

Date HM Interview: 50

[image]

Comment: I understood none of that.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have dates in your table in a certain format and want user to be able to enter the filter dates in any format?

Why not use a date picker for input fields? That way, you won't have to worry about formatting. 

Please modify the question if I understood it wrong.

Comment: I edited it. Hope it is clearer

Comment: Would you be able to share the data in a google spreadsheet? That should improve your chances in getting an answer fast.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: This works. Where each cell between &-& is a filter. It gives a complete dynamic dashboard

=QUERY('JV Database'!A1:X7394,"select* where (G contains '"&C1&"') and (((R > date '"&A1&"') and (R < date '"&B1&"')) or ((S > date '"&A1&"') and (S < date '"&B1&"')) or ((T > date '"&A1&"') and (T < date '"&B1&"')) or ((W > date '"&A1&"') and (W < date '"&B1&"')) or ((V > date '"&A1&"') and (V < date '"&B1&"'))) and (D contains '"&D1&"') and (C contains '"&E1&"') and (A contains '"&F1&"') ")